# CaseShare created by partner record disappears

Tags: apex-managed-sharing

I am trying to beat this old problem of being unable to share partner cases with it's sibling partner users.

I've implemented Apex managed sharing, but facing odd behaviour. I can see in debug log the CaseShare are getting inserted (as a partner) with no exceptions, but they magically disappear immediately after.

Inserting the very same record as system admin works perfectly fine. Running class with or without sharing does not change behaviour.

```
public static void commitShares ( case[] cases){

    caseshare[] shares = new caseshare[]{};

    set<id> accountIds = new set<id>();
    map<id,id> userRoles = new map<id,id>();
    map<id,id> groupRoles = new map<id,id>();
    map<id,id> accountGroups = new map<id,id>();


    for ( case o : cases )
        if ( o.accountId != null )
            accountIds.add( o.accountId );

    map<id,account> caseAccounts = new map<id, account>([select id, ownerId
                                                         from account where id in 
                                                         (select accountid from case where id =: cases)
                                                         and owner.isActive = true ]);

    for ( case o : [select id, ownerid, accountid
                        from case where id =: cases
                        and accountId != null
                        and account.owner.isactive = true])
        if ( caseAccounts.get(o.accountId) != null && o.ownerId != caseAccounts.get(o.accountId).ownerid )
            shares.add (
                new caseshare ( 
                    caseId = o.id,
                    UserOrGroupId = caseAccounts.get(o.accountId).ownerid,
                    CaseAccessLevel  = 'Read' ) );

    for (user u : [select userroleid, 
                   accountId from 
                   user where accountId =: accountIds ])
        userRoles.put( u.userroleid, u.accountId );

    for (group u: [ select id, relatedid
                   from group 
                   where relatedid =: userRoles.keySet() 
                   and type='RoleAndSubordinates'])
        groupRoles.put( u.relatedid, u.id );    

    for ( id i : groupRoles.keyset() )
        accountGroups.put( userRoles.get( i ) , groupRoles.get( i ) );

    for ( case o : cases )
        if( accountGroups.get( o.accountid ) != null )
            shares.add(
                new caseshare ( 
                    caseId = o.id,
                    UserOrGroupId = accountGroups.get( o.accountid ),
                    CaseAccessLevel  = 'Read'));
    system.debug(shares);
    insert shares;
}
```

**Edit**: Could the default Case Owner be the reason. I found somewhere that Manual shares will disappear whenever case owner changes.

Answer (score 1):

So yes, turns out manual shares disappear after owner changes, which happens by default on cases. Adjusted trigger to run after owner update and now it works fine.